# How to have default data to wysiwyg editor in magento

Tags: php, email, magento, editor, wysiwyg

I need some data added default in the editor.
Like I want a template to get loaded in editor when I click on edit template option..
Can anyone suggest me some tip??

Comment: I guess you are talking about the transactional emails?

Comment: Yes just like that
BUT in my own module how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see how it can be done

$dataa= $this->getTemplate1();

```
    $fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
        'name' => 'content',
        'label' => Mage::helper('abandonedcart')->__('Content'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('abandonedcart')->__('Content'),
        'style' => 'width:700px; height:500px;',
        'wysiwyg' => true,
        'required' => true,
        'state' => 'html',
        'config' => $wysiwygConfig,
        'value'=> $dataa,

    ));

    if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getAbandonedcartData()) {
        $form->addValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getAbandonedcartData());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setAbandonedcartData(null);
    } elseif (Mage::registry('abandonedcart_data')) {
        $form->addValues(Mage::registry('abandonedcart_data')->getData());
    }
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

and calling a function to have data

```
public function getTemplate1() {
    $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('abandonedcart_abandonedcart_group_email_template');
     $emailTemplate['template_text'];;
       $template_id = Mage::getStoreConfig('abandonedcart/abandonedcart_group/email_template');       
       $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);

 return    $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate();   



}
```